# Singleton class of Media player with setOnCompletionListener()

Tags: android, singleton, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-music-player

I know there are lots of topics on MediaPlayer. I created a singleton class for media player which works fine. When I implement setOnCompletionListeners in each activity only the latest one works, which is weird. My question is when I create a singleton class for media player, is it necessary to include setOnCompletionListeners, setOnErrorListeners in the singleton class or can I implement these independently in all classes?

My singleton class:

```
public class MyMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer  {

private static MyMediaPlayer mpclass ;




private MyMediaPlayer() {

}

public static MyMediaPlayer getInstance() {
    if (mpclass == null) {
        synchronized (MyMediaPlayer.class) {
            if (mpclass == null) {
                mpclass = new MyMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    }

    return mpclass;
}
```